# undefined method "content" em Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, gem

Estou tentando rodar esse arquivo em Ruby:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/http'

https = Net::HTTP.new('onebitcode.com', 443)
https.use_ssl = true

response = https.get("/")

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)

h1 = doc.at('h1')

puts h1.content
```

Mas recebo esse erro:

> "web.rb:13:in `<main>': undefined method` content' for nil:NilClass
> (NoMethodError)".

Eu rodava ele em outra máquina e funcionava antes, agora não sei o que é.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

O método [`Nokogiri::XML::Searchable#at`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#method-i-at) retorna o elemento ou `nil`. No seu caso, esse elemento `h1` que você está procurando não existe na página. Talvez já tenha existido em alguma outra versão dela. É por isso que a exceção `NoMethodError` estoura.

Basta rodar um `curl -L onebitcode.com | grep h1` para ver que esse `grep` não acha nada contendo nem o texto `h1` no documento inteiro.

Uma sugestão é colocar um nil-check para evitar a exceção. Por exemplo:

```rb
puts h1.content unless h1.nil?
```